# Is it fair to ask "How do I make/get/do Feature X" without a clue?

Tags: discussion

I see a few questions posting a link to a website and asking, "Cool? How do you do that?" with nothing else. I imagine the questioner may not have a clue about relevant buzzwords or "hidden" (not obvious in source) technologies at play.

So, I think it's a fair question to gain knowledge, but is it really appropriate for Stack Overflow? Often the protocol is to post a question and relevant code or answer "What have you tried?" So, if you don't have a clue, should you not post at all? Or is there a better place in the Stack Exchange network or in the larger web?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> So, I think it's a fair question to gain knowledge,

Agreed

> but is it really appropriate for Stack Overflow?

[Nope](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LJP1DphOWPs&feature=youtube_gdata_player).

Questions on Stack Overflow have to be specific, and (essentially) have a single correct answer.  Showing a link to a web page that, for example, slides a div across the screen, and then ask how that's done could garner endless correct answers on how to duplicate that particular effect.

Comment: Should they be marked off-topic then?

Comment: I would guess not a real question would be more appropriate, but others may disagree.

Comment: Hmm, are you implying that Stack Overflow has the most life-like dead animals around?

Comment: @The - I've never thought about it like that.  But now that you mention it....

Comment: Anyway, more constructively, you think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229687/creating-an-email-to-user-control) is not an acceptable SO question? It looks OK to me...

Comment: @The - it's borderline.  I'd leave it if it were up to me, but I'm rather surprised it didn't get any close votes.